# Filter NSMutableArray with All the values of nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have MutableArray like this...

```
    restaurants = ({
    cuisines =   ({
                    "cuisine_id" = 1;
                    "cuisine_name" = Indian;
                },
                {
                    "cuisine_id" = 2;
                    "cuisine_name" = SriLanka;
                }
            );}

            { cuisines = ({
                    "cuisine_id" = 1;
                    "cuisine_name" = Chinese;
                },
                {
                    "cuisine_id" = 2;
                    "cuisine_name" = Afghani;
                }
            );}

           {cuisines =({
                    "cuisine_id" = 1;
                    "cuisine_name" = Chinese;
                },
                {
                    "cuisine_id" = 2;
                    "cuisine_name" = Afghani;
                }
            );}
        )
```

And I'm Filtering Restaurants Array With multiple values of cuisine_name 
For Example if I have a,

Nsarray like this cuisine_name (
Indian,
Srilankan,
Chinese,
)

I want to filter my Restaurants array on basis of each object of cusine_name.

At present I'm doing like this..

```
        NSPredicate *predicateCuisines = [NSPredicate   predicateWithFormat:@"(cuisines.cuisine_name = %@)",[cuisineTypes      valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]];
    [self.arrRestaurantList filterUsingPredicate:predicateCuisines];
```

But it filtering Using description...For Restaurant Array which contains whole three values(Indian,Srilankan,Chinese) but i want to filter with each object of cuisine_name.
Any help will really appreciated..

Comment: what you mean by    cusine_name == ?

Comment: cuisine_name is Nsdicationary variable as u can see from cuisines array and i want to filter this restaurant array on the basis of individual cuisine_name. I have another array of cuisine_name too..

Comment: plz chek my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz use this

```
  NSArray* arrtu4 = @[@{@"cuisines" : @[@{@"cuisine_id" : @1,@"cuisine_name" : @"Indian"},@{ @"cuisine_id" : @2, @"cuisine_name" : @"SriLanka"}]},@{ @"cuisines" : @[@{@"cuisine_id" : @1,@"cuisine_name" : @"Chinese"},@{@"cuisine_id" : @2,@"cuisine_name" : @"Afghani"}]},@{@"cuisines" :@[@{@"cuisine_id" :@1,@"cuisine_name" : @"Chinese"},@{ @"cuisine_id" : @2,@"cuisine_name" : @"Afghani"}]}];
    NSMutableArray *arrryfilted = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *arrayCountrys = @[@"Chinese",@"SriLanka",@"Indian"];

for (int i = 0; i<arrtu4.count; i++)
{

    NSArray *filterArray2 = [[arrtu4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"cuisines"];

    NSArray *filterArray3 = [filterArray2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
        return [arrayCountrys containsObject:[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]]  ;

                }]];




     [arrryfilted addObjectsFromArray:filterArray3 ];



}

NSLog(@"%@",arrryfilted);
```

output:

```
2016-08-20 16:44:59.856 coredataReltaion[6762:152672] (
        {
        "cuisine_id" = 1;
        "cuisine_name" = Indian;
    },
        {
        "cuisine_id" = 2;
        "cuisine_name" = SriLanka;
    },
        {
        "cuisine_id" = 1;
        "cuisine_name" = Chinese;
    },
        {
        "cuisine_id" = 1;
        "cuisine_name" = Chinese;
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...What is [evaluatedObject valueForKey:cuisine_name]

Comment: use @"cuisine_name" here cuisine_name is object of your Nsdicationary

Comment: Sry but it get a Exception     ..valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cuisine_name.'

Comment: can you show me values of arrRestaurantList and  [cuisineTypes      valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]

Comment: arrRestaurant I already shown you... and   [cuisineTypes valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]  = (Srilankan,Chinese,Indian) and i want to filter arrRestaurant  which seprate value of Srilankan,chinese and indian..

Comment: there are multiple  cuisines array in restaurant array . so you have to  check every cuisines in restaurant array  with objects at index.

Comment: plz wait i will give the answer.

Comment: Ok Let me check..And i'll let you know

Comment: [evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]   isEqualToString:@"Indian"] || [[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]   isEqualToString:@"SriLanka"] || [[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"cuisine_name"]   isEqualToString:@"Chinese"]    This value can be 50 also...

Comment: wait for 5 mint let me check for this condition.

Comment: @MohammedHussain check the update i use arrayCountrys.

Comment: yes @MohammedHussain containsObject work properly. plz see you have some other issue.

Comment: @MohammedHussain if my answer help you plz mark it right.